# Replace one number in range with word

Tags: python, range

I am trying to change the number in the range into word forma. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
n=range(1,101,2)
if n == 55:
    print ('Fifty-Five')
else:
    print n
```

Comment: @iCodez: that indentation error was in the original post. Correcting it may have inadvertently corrected (part) of the problem.

Comment: `n` is a `range` object, not an int. Are you intending to iterate over the values in the range? Or just choose one value?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Sorry, I just thought you missed that.  It's hard to tell either way.  If anything, it will save more `IndentationError` questions from being asked. :)

Comment: just trying to choose one value to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a for loop:

```
for n in range(1, 101, 2):
    if n == 55:
        print("Fifty-five")
    else:
        print(n)
```

Comment: @WiiloGeedi no problem, glad to help. Once the question is 15 minutes old, you may choose to click the check mark next to my answer to mark it as the correct one. Doing this also marks the question as resolved, and earns [reputation points](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) for both of us. For more information, see [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)